# onClick() for spinner or something similar

Tags: java, android

this may be a simple question but i was wondering, i have an application that has two spinners and a textview which displays a boolean. the two spinners have numbers between 1 and 10 and i want the boolean to display true when ever the numbers from the two spinners equal  to 12. i have all the code to do this and to check are the numbers in the spinners = 12 but i dont know where to put the code to check are the numbers = 12 when ever one of the spinners are changed

so long story short, is there a onClick command i can use to call this code when ever someone clicks on a spinner and changes the number in the spinner?

Thanks

Comment: by _spinner_, do you mean `JSpinner`?

Comment: @noob - Its android. You don't use JComponents

Comment: @Spidy: missed the _android_ tag .. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use an on item selected listener:

```
   spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            // Here you check the spinner values sum
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Get an instance of the spinner and add a listener for when an item is selected. That way it will trigger after the user has clicked the spinner, and selected a value.

```
Spinner s = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.myspinner);
s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }   
});
```

Comment: cheers :) man ive been at this too long... didnt even think of this :P

Comment: it always gets me when its not under AddListener. Android does a lot of setOnListener

Answer (score 0):

onItemSelected()

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html